# Winlibs and libcurl

Tags: libcurl, mingw-w64

I am asking here because I couldn't get any support elsewhere. Also consider that I am quite a beginner so bear patience.

I am using Winlibs (winlibs.com, a ready to use mingw gcc10+ distribution) to code under Windows because after having tried other alternatives I judged it the best to my purposes, easiest to install and the most functional. I never had any problems with it.

But recently I had the need of writing some simple code to send a POST request. I wanted to do it in a possibly portable and c++ friendly manner, so I was suggested to use Curl. No libcurl is included in winlibs so I tried to load one from here

https://curl.se/download.html

I chose the windows 64 binary of course (7.83.1) since I am working on windows 64 with winlibs 64. I installed everything in the right place and linked against libcurl.a.

Unfortunately the linker complains of unresolved symbols so I have to supppose the curl binaries I used are not suitable.

How can I use libcurl with winlibs then ? Before bothering here I really googled but could find no info!

Comment: "Windows 64 bit" is not suitable to your build environment, you must download "Windows 64 bit - cygwin".

Comment: @273K there are two cygwin downloads in the download page, but one contains the curl executable (not the linker lib) and the other contains the .dll. Is there any libcurl.a binary ready somewhere suitable for mingw ? Thanks

Comment: @elena Oh, it is not well. They do not include development files into the official libcurl cygwin distributions for some reasons. But they are available here https://mirrors.kernel.org/sources.redhat.com/cygwin/x86_64/release/curl/libcurl-devel/

Comment: Well, after your edit, it looks much better, so ...

Comment: @273K Thanks, I tired the one in the link you posted. Unfortunately it links OK but requires a .dll. In fact it is named libcurl.dll.a not without a reason. I don't want to force users to install any 3rd party dll, that's why I wanted *static linking*. This one is actually statically linked but acts as a wrapper to curl dll!  Isn't there really any chance to static link with curl and mingw ?? No working libcurl.a ? Again, I could find no info by googling... :(

Comment: Build what you need from the sources.

Comment: @273K yeah that's their phylosophy but one is not meant to have the time or even the capability to compile everything. There is everything online, so I judge very strange and disappointing that there is *not* such a thing as a ready to use libcurl.a for mingw!! Given how popular libcurl is, since everytime you ask how to do something they suggest you "use curl"

Comment: Mingw is not so popular like you think it is. I do not know why it is so popular in student tasks. Perhaps because Visual Studio was stuck on supporting the limited subset of ANSI C89 only until Visual Studio 2015, when they started to support C99 (with the 15 years gap).

Comment: In the end I had to give up. I even tried with MSYS2 linking with all the referenced libs by libcurl, it is a hopeless job. They are just too many, beyond those officially listed. Looks like using libcurl with MinGW is really a no go.

Answer (score 2):

The MinGW-w64 tools from https://winlibs.com/ are only a build toolchain, so they don't contain libraries for you to link with (yet).

You need a Windows build of libcurl and use that.

To use it you must include the location to the header files using the `-I` compiler flag, and then link with the library by pointing to the location of the `.a` file with the `-L` linker flag and then link with the library using the `-l` flag (`-lcurl` in this case). If you don't have `.a` files you can also try to link with the full path of the `.dll` file and gcc will know it's a shared library.

An easier way is to get libcurl via MSYS2's `pacman` package manager.
If you want to statically link you need to use the output of `pkg-config --static --libs libcurl` as link flags.

In practice though I noticed that sometomes `pkg-config --static --libs libcurl` is missing some dependencies and you still need to add some manually. An example of a project of mine that builds on Windows with winlibs MinGW-w64 (both 32-bit and 64-bit) can be found at https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_tools/blob/main/Makefile (specifically look for the definition of `CURL_LDFLAGS`)